# Is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I've recently asked a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66553/is-it-possible-to-charge-my-phone-and-tablet-with-wifi) and it was put on hold for being an Android Independent question.

I don't believe the question is actually Android Independent and it seems to fit the help center guidelines fairly

`If your question generally covers...`

`Using your Android device`
`Using a particular app on your Android device`
`Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device`

While the technology in the question might not be completely finished yet, I think that it may very well become relevant in the future. However, I don't think this is a good enough reason to consider it off topic.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as "WiFi charging". Apps that purport to do this are hoaxes.

If you're asking about *wireless* charging that might be a different matter, as there are a few devices that use the technology and it looks to become even more common. (The new Motorola 360 watch is rumored to use wireless charging.)

But then, you're asking about a company who might be doing something in this arena and if you can get into their beta program. That's off-topic here. Go ask them.

Frankly, I think the question was closed for the wrong reason, but it should be closed.

If you have a *specific* question about an issue with wireless charging on your Android device, by all means add it. But the question you ask is either vague and speculative or not really about Android and is likely to be outdated and useless relatively quickly.

Comment: True, wireless charging would probably be a better term to use. A more accurate depiction of my question would be regarding wireless charging that is effective for a distance more than 2 centimeters.

Comment: That's still overly broad. Stack Exchange works best for _specific_ questions, and I still don't see how it's specifically Android.

Comment: Remember also that Closing is not necessarily an end state. ***Edit*** your question to make it more appropriate and it can be re-opened.